# What happens if I don't give Ashley a gift right when she wakes up?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What happens if I don't give Ashley the gift right after she wakes up?

1. Will I have another chance to give her the gift?
2. If I bought the wrong gift will there be another chance to buy the right one and give it to her?
3. If I didn't give it to her would that cause anything bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments on [two](http://www.gamefront.com/mass-effect-3-male-shepard-romance-guide/) GameFront [articles](http://www.gamefront.com/mass-effect-3-how-to-romance-ashley/): "Buying Ashley is gift is NOT required to have a romantic relationship with her, but it does help" and "The gift isn’t completely essential!".  So you should be OK as long as you're doing most other things right.

If you're worried about what gift to get, the guides say:

> Even when she’s unconscious in the Citadel, visit her and offer some kind words anyway. While there, you can purchase a special item, a Tennyson Collection, at the store terminal in the hospital lobby. You may have to wait until she’s awake to purchase and gift the special item.

Comment: thank you man you made me cool :D building your own story in mass effect is avery wired thing   thank you guys

Answer (score 5):

1. **No**, you will not have another chance to give her a gift.
2. **No**, if you screwed up on the gift, there's no chance to make it right.
3. **Maybe**. The gift is one of a number of ways you can build trust and repoire with the Virmire Survivior (either Ashley or Kaidan) prior to the events on the Citadel after curing the Genophage. Whether you've built up enough trust with them will determine whether they will believe you outright when you confront them, require a hard, or possibly even max level Charm/Intimidation check to persuade, or if you've been truly neglectful and/or hostile, they may be unable to be swayed. If you can't make the dialog check or the check is not there, you'll be unable to take them into your squad as events unfold which make them irrevocably unavailable to you. These factors include:

   - Whether you saved the Council in the original **Mass Effect**
   - Whether you pursued a romance with them in the original **Mass Effect**
   - Your response in conversations on Mars regarding your prior work with Cerberus, and whether you can be trusted.
   - How many times you visited them in the hospital between missions, *and your gift*, if applicable.
   - If you romanced them in **ME1**, whether you pursued a different romance in **ME2**

     - If you did, whether you were honest and/or apologetic about that alternative romance.
   - Your use of Paragon or Renegade interrupts in the final conversation.
   - If Major Kirrahe or Thane Krios have been kept alive through the previous two games. In the case of Thane, you'll need to have visited *him* in the hospital prior to this mission.

Comment: I couldn't find where to buy the gift, and nothing drastic happened.  It may have taken her a little longer for her to warm up to me again, but I've got that train on the tracks now.

Comment: @MBraedley Indeed, as I note, buying the gift is only one factor of many. It's entirely possible that you'll be fine, but it depends on how the other factors are handled.

Comment: i did all that you informed about the romance in previous me i was loyal for ash since part one even with marinda the hot chick i resistaned hhhhh :D and i was honest about making cerburace work for me and she said i love you the conversation before they went directly to the archives in mars so the present is not big deal right here no?

Comment: @crouch probably. Unfortunately I don't have the exact formula (since presumably there's some sort of hidden 'trust points mechanic') to be sure. Best I can say is that no one element on the list should be a deal breaker.